# How to name a variable with index to store the input mxArray?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I want to realize a function to translate the input variable of mxArray(from Matlab) to C++. For detail, if the input variable is a cell, it will be arranged to a vector.(Edited following advices) Like below,

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> transfer(const mxArray* ix)
{
    mwSize Num = mxGetNumberOfElements(ix);
    mxArray* ptr = NULL;
    mxDouble* ptr_double;
    vector<vector<int>> V(Num);
    mwSize Num0;
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)Num; i++) {
        ptr = mxGetCell(ix, i);
        Num0 = mxGetNumberOfElements(ptr);
        ptr_double = mxGetPr(ptr);
        for (j = 0; j < (int)Num0; j++) {
            V[i].push_back(*ptr_double++);
        }
    }
    return V;
}
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrhs; i++) {
        if (mxIsCell(prhs[i])) {
            vector<vector<int>>  V1 = transfer(prhs[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < V1.size(); j++)
            {   
                for (int k = 0; k < V1[j].size(); k++) {
                    mexPrintf("  %d", V1[j][k]);
                }
                mexPrintf("\n size is %d\n", V1[j].size());
            }
        }
       //else
    }
    return;
}
```

I now have a problem to name the above variable. I have to name the variable (like `V1`) corresponding to the index `i`(`1` in the example). But I don't know how to realize it in c++. Could you tell me how to do it in C++?

I have searched a little on Internet and I found it seems impossible to have an dynamic name in C++. If this is true, Could anyone have some idea how to arrange these input variables, which type is vector> and double array? Perhaps struct? Then how to initial the struct dynamically is a bigger challenge to me. 
Besides, I want to do this because I am using OpenMP which could not have any variable or pointer related to Matlab in the parallel loops. I must copy all the data from `mx-` to C++ supported type data(like `vector`).

Comment: It is unclear to me what you intend this code to do.  Some issues: (1) Why are you creating ptr in the first place? Why not just use the result of the mxGetCell call directly? (2) You don't have any checks to see if mxGetCell actually contains a non-empty full double variable, so mxGetPr or dereferencing the point p might crash (3) There is no point in incrementing p++ in your current code. Did you intend to copy all of the elements of the cell?  Please clarify this with details of what you want the result to be, maybe with a small example.

Comment: @JamesTursa I have edited my code following your issues and make a whole script. I just want to copy the input matlab format data to c++ format(vector or array).Because the OpenMP is always crash with Matlab `mx-` like data.I just want to dynamically arrange a variable to the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide function.

BTW, `new mxArray * [Num]` is bad idea. use `std::vector<mxArray>`

```cpp
void transfer_impl(vector<vector<int>>& V, mxDouble*& ptr, mwSize Num0){
    for (mwSize i = 0; j < Num0; j++) {
        V[i].push_back(*ptr_double++);
    }
}
```

> Because the OpenMP is always crash

You should consider using C++17 Parallel Algorithms.

Comment: I have delete the part for `new mxArray`.Could you explain a little of `divide function`? I don't know what it means exactly. Does it means using template or `map`? Thank you.

Comment: I see you are using the input variable address to make an implicit output. This is a very clever solution. Thank you. As for C++17, I need some time to learn it. Even though OpenMP always crashed, it is very easy to apply.

Comment: I found your code only has one loop. I need to arrange every `cell` element in to a vector. So I think it is necessary to have two nested loops. Is it right?

Comment: Call it from transfer's for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <omp.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<double>> transfer(const mxArray* ix) // changed to double
{
    mwSize Num = mxGetNumberOfElements(ix);
    mxArray* ptr = NULL;
    mxDouble* ptr_double;
    vector<vector<double>> V(Num); // changed to double
    mwSize Num0;
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < (int)Num; i++) {
        ptr = mxGetCell(ix, i);
        if( ptr ) { // check for NULL pointer
            if( !mxIsDouble(ptr) || mxIsComplex(ptr) || mxIsSparse(ptr) ) { // check for proper type etc.
                mexErrMsgTxt("cell must contain full real double");
            }
            Num0 = mxGetNumberOfElements(ptr);
            ptr_double = mxGetPr(ptr);
            for (j = 0; j < (int)Num0; j++) {
                V[i].push_back(*ptr_double++);
            }
        }
    }
    return V;
}
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray* plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray* prhs[])
{
        for (int i = 0; i < nrhs; i++) {
        if (mxIsCell(prhs[i])) {
            vector<vector<double>>  V1 = transfer(prhs[i]); // changed to double
            for (int j = 0; j < V1.size(); j++)
            {   
                for (int k = 0; k < V1[j].size(); k++) {
                    mexPrintf("  %g", V1[j][k]); // changed to %g
                }
                mexPrintf("\n size is %d\n", V1[j].size());
            }
        }
       //else
    }
    return;
}
```